# Theorem 2.1.5 in Durrett's Probability Theory and Examples- don't understand the proof in the book

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm reading Durrett's Probability Theory and Examples (4th ed.) and I am having a hard time understanding the proof of Theorem 2.1.5:

Suppose $\mathcal{F_{i,j}}$, $1\leq i \leq n$, $1\leq j \leq m(i)$ are independent and let $\mathcal{G_{i}}=\sigma(\bigcup_{j}\mathcal{F_{i,j}})$. Then $\mathcal{G_{1}},...,\mathcal{G_{n}}$ are independent.

Proof in Durrett: 
Let $\mathcal{A_{i}}$ be the collection of sets of the form $\bigcap_{j}A_{i,j}$ where ${A_{i,j}}\in\mathcal{F_{i,j}}$. $\mathcal{A_{i}}$ is a $\pi$-system that contains $\Omega$ and contains $\bigcup_{j}\mathcal{F_{i,j}}$ so theorem 2.1.3 implies that $\sigma(\mathcal{A_{i}})=\mathcal{G_{i}}$ are independent.

I don't understand a couple of things in this proof:

i) why does $\mathcal{A_{i}}$ contain $\bigcup_{j}\mathcal{F_{i,j}}$ ?   I've tried proving that an element of $\bigcup_{j}\mathcal{F_{i,j}}$ must be in $\mathcal{A_{i}}$, but to no avail as of yet.

ii) even if I prove that $\bigcup_{j}\mathcal{F_{i,j}}\subset \mathcal{A_{i}}$ does the fact then somehow imply that $\sigma(\mathcal{A_{i}})=\sigma(\bigcup_{j}\mathcal{F_{i,j}})=\mathcal{G_{i}}$  ?

I've been struggling with this for a while and have run out of ideas on how to prove this or what Durrett is doing here. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the $m(i)$ in the quantifier for $\mathcal F_{i,j}$?

Comment: The book doesn't specify, but I assume m(i) is an integer, so for each i, there will be (potentially) a different range for j?

Comment: $m(i)$ is some finite number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1), for some sets $A_i \in \cup_{j} \mathcal{F_{i,j}}$, there exists $j$ such that $A_i\in \mathcal{F_{i,j}}$. Denote such $A_i$ as $A_{i,j}$. So $A_{i,j}\in \cap_{j} A_{i,j}$.

For (2), if you want to show two sigma-algebra are equal that is $\sigma(\mathcal{A}_{i})=\sigma(\cup_j\mathcal{F_{i,j}})$. It suffices to prove $\mathcal{A}_{i}\subset \sigma(\cup_j\mathcal{F_{i,j}})$ and $\cup_j\mathcal{F_{i,j}}\subset \sigma(\mathcal{A}_{i})$. Note that $\cup_{j}\mathcal{F_{i,j}}\subset \mathcal{A}_{i}$ then $\sigma(\cup_{j}\mathcal{F_{i,j}})\subset \sigma(\mathcal{A}_{i})$. Conversely, it is clear that $\mathcal{A}_{i}\subset \sigma(\cup_j\mathcal{F_{i,j}})$.

Comment: Thanks! Got it now